# can't update R package documentation: `System command 'R' failed` (#using statements don't work)

Tags: c++, r, linux, rcpp, devtools

I have a [RcppEigen project](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfexamplesinr) that I'm trying to update documentation for. This project only exports one c++ function into R.

Unfortunately, I get a problem when I run either `devtools::document(pkg = "~/pfexamplesinr/")` or `roxygen2::roxygenize(roclets="rd", package.dir = "pfexamplesinr/")` The error message is below.

It says something about `System command 'R' failed`. The entire build output is too large to paste (I go over the character limit). If I search for the first error, it's `RcppExports.cpp:15:21: error: ‘Map’ was not declared in this scope`. Is there some funny business about the order of `#include` directives and  `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]` statements?

Note: the code builds fine when I use `Rcpp::sourceCpp('pfexamplesinr/src/likelihoods.cpp')`

Edit: this problem goes away when I remove the `#using` statements, and prepend `Eigen::` whenever necessary.

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include "svol_sisr_hilb.h"
#include "resamplers.h"

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// choose number of particles, and number of bits for inverse Hilbert curve map  
#define NP 500
#define NB 5
#define debug_mode false


using Eigen::Map; 
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using hilb_sys_resamp_T = pf::resamplers::sys_hilb_resampler<NP,1,NB,double>;
using svol_pfilter = svol_sisr_hilb<NP,NB, hilb_sys_resamp_T, double, debug_mode>; 

// helpful notes:
// 1. 
// parameters passed to svol_pfilter() ctor are in the following order: phi, beta, sigma
// 2.
// uProposal will be dimension (time X (particles + 1))
// first NP columns will be used for state sampling 
// last column will be used for resampling at each time point
// 3. 
// choosing NP or NB too large will result in stackoverflow
// number of particles is set in two places: in the #define directive and also used in  your R script


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double svolApproxLL(const Map<VectorXd> y, const Map<VectorXd> thetaProposal, const Map<MatrixXd> uProposal) {

  // construct particle filter object
  svol_pfilter pf(thetaProposal(0), thetaProposal(1), thetaProposal(2)); // order: phi, beta, sigma

  // iterate over the data 
  double log_like(0.0);
  Eigen::Matrix<double,1,1> yt;
  std::array<Eigen::Matrix<double,1,1>, NP> uStateTransition;
  Eigen::Matrix<double,1,1> uResample;
  for(int time = 0; time < y.rows(); ++time){
    
    // change types of inputs
    yt(0) = y(time);
    for(unsigned particle = 0; particle < NP; ++particle) {
      uStateTransition[particle] = uProposal.block(time,particle,1,1); 
    }
    uResample(0) = uProposal(time,NP);
    
    // std::cout << yt.transpose() << "\n";
    // for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NP; ++i)
    //   std::cout << uStateTransition[i] << ", ";
    // std::cout << "\n----------\n";
    
    // update particle filter and log-likelihood    
    pf.filter(yt, uStateTransition, uResample);
    log_like += pf.getLogCondLike();
  }
    
  //return es.eigenvalues();
  return log_like;
}

// You can include R code blocks in C++ files processed with sourceCpp
// (useful for testing and development). The R code will be automatically 
// run after the compilation.


/*** R
numTime <- 3
numParts <- 500 # make sure this agrees with NP
u <- matrix(rnorm(numTime*(numParts+1)), ncol = numParts+1)
params <- c(.9, 1, .1) # -1 < phi < 1, beta, sigma > 0
hist(replicate(100, svolApproxLL(rnorm(numTime), params, u)))
*/
```

```
Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  : 
  System command 'R' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr (last 10 lines):
E> /home/taylor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >’
E> /home/taylor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:98:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >’
E> /home/taylor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:178:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>’
E> /home/taylor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/InputParameter.h:77:11:   required from ‘class Rcpp::ConstReferenceInputParameter<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >’
E> RcppExports.cpp:43:74:   required from here
E> /home/taylor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:5
```

Comment: People will need more than the last ten lines of compiler output to help you debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for providing the URL to the repro.  This error, as it happens not infrequently, appears to be one deeper down 'hidden' by `devtools::document()`.

When I clone your repo onto a machine with 'current everything' from CRAN running Ubuntu 21.04 and doing my usual two-step of

```
compAttr.r       # shell wrapper for Rcpp::compileAttributes
roxy.r -f        # shell wrapper for roxygenize()
```

(using these helper scripts from my littler package),
I end in tears because your code uses C++17 statements without specifying C++17 as a compilation standard.

In other words, a vanilla bug at your end, independent of Rcpp or other tools.

```
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr(master)$ compAttr.r 
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr(master)$ roxy.r -f                              
ℹ Loading pfexamplesinr                   
Exports from /home/edd/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr/src/likelihoods.cpp:
   double svolApproxLL(Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> y, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> thetaProposal, Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> uProposal)
                                                    
Exports from /home/edd/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr/src/rcppeigen_hello_world.cpp:
   Eigen::MatrixXd rcppeigen_hello_world()                                                               
   Eigen::MatrixXd rcppeigen_outerproduct(const Eigen::VectorXd& x)
   double rcppeigen_innerproduct(const Eigen::VectorXd& x)
   Rcpp::List rcppeigen_bothproducts(const Eigen::VectorXd& x)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Exports from /home/edd/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr/src/resamplers.h:                                                                                                                                                                                      
Exports from /home/edd/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr/src/rv_eval.h:                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                         
Exports from /home/edd/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr/src/rv_samp.h:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   /home/edd/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr/src/RcppExports.cpp updated.                                                                                                                                    
/home/edd/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr/R/RcppExports.R updated.                                                                                                                                        
Re-compiling pfexamplesinr                                                                               
─  installing *source* package ‘pfexamplesinr’ ...                                                       
   ** using staged installation

   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   ccache g++  -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include'    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-unused -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-class-memaccess -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
   ccache g++  -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include'    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-unused -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-class-memaccess -c likelihoods.cpp -o likelihoods.o
   In file included from svol_sisr_hilb.h:8,
                    from likelihoods.cpp:1:
   sisr_filter.h: In member function ‘void pf::filters::SISRFilter<nparts, dimx, dimy, resamp_t, float_t, debug>::filter(const osv&, const std::vector<std::function<const Eigen::Matrix<float_t, -1, -1>(const Eigen::Matrix<float_t, dimx, 1>&)> >&)’:
   sisr_filter.h:229:16: warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
     229 |             if constexpr(debug)
         |                ^~~~~~~~~
   sisr_filter.h:262:16: warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
     262 |             if constexpr(debug)
         |                ^~~~~~~~~
   sisr_filter.h:288:16: warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
     288 |             if constexpr(debug)
         |                ^~~~~~~~~
   sisr_filter.h:320:16: warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
     320 |             if constexpr(debug)
         |                ^~~~~~~~~
   sisr_filter.h: In member function ‘void pf::filters::SISRFilterCRN<nparts, dimx, dimy, dimu, dimur, resamp_t, float_t, debug>::filter(const osv&, const arrayUs&, const usvr&, const std::vector<std::function<const Eigen::Matrix<float_t, -1, -1>(const Eigen::Matrix<float_t, dimx, 1>&)> >&)’:
   sisr_filter.h:559:16: warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
     559 |             if constexpr(debug)
         |                ^~~~~~~~~
   sisr_filter.h:592:16: warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
     592 |             if constexpr(debug)
         |                ^~~~~~~~~
   sisr_filter.h:618:16: warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
     618 |             if constexpr(debug)
         |                ^~~~~~~~~
   sisr_filter.h:650:16: warning: ‘if constexpr’ only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’
     650 |             if constexpr(debug)
         |                ^~~~~~~~~
   In file included from likelihoods.cpp:2:
   resamplers.h: In member function ‘void pf::resamplers::sys_hilb_resampler<nparts, dimx, num_hilb_bits, float_t>::resampLogWts(pf::resamplers::sys_hilb_resampler<nparts, dimx, num_hilb_bits, float_t>::arrayVec&, pf::resamplers::sys_hilb_resampler<nparts, dimx, num_hilb_bits, float_t>::arrayFloat&, const usvr&) [with long unsigned int nparts = 500; long unsigned int dimx = 1; long unsigned int num_hilb_bits = 5; float_t = double]’:
   resamplers.h:1089:36: warning: ‘idx’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    1089 |         tmpPartics[i] = sortedParts[idx];
         |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~^
   ccache g++  -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include'    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-unused -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-class-memaccess -c rcppeigen_hello_world.cpp -o rcppeigen_hello_world.o
   ccache g++ -std=gnu++14 -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o pfexamplesinr.so RcppExports.o likelihoods.o rcppeigen_hello_world.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
   installing to /tmp/devtools_install_2dc74d5a52ad61/00LOCK-pfexamplesinr/00new/pfexamplesinr/libs
   ** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
─  DONE (pfexamplesinr)
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/68985867/pfexamplesinr(master)$
```